# Default scope for a joined table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to select only program schedule where it belongs to a channel with ctype = TV

but I get this error:

[image]

**Program** (Model)

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :program_schedules, dependent: :delete_all
```

**ProgramSchedule** (Model)

```
class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :channel


  default_scope { includes(:channel).where("program_schedules.channels.ctype NOT IN (?)", ['tv']) }

end
```

**Channel** (Model)

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :site, :ctype, :country, :presence => true

  has_many :programs, :dependent => :delete_all
```

**QUERY**

```
@programs = Program.includes(:program_schedules).where(
                             "programs.ptype" => ["tv_show","movie"],
                                "programs.country" => @country).
                          select("programs.id").
                          group("programs.id, program_schedules.id, channels.id").
                          having("program_schedules.stop > ?", Time.current)
```

**Schema.rb**

```
  create_table "channels", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "site"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "icon"
    t.string   "ctype"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "lang"
    t.integer  "ordertab"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "homepage"
  end

      create_table "programs", force: true do |t|
    t.string "country"
    t.string "title"
    t.text   "subtitle"
    t.text   "description"
    t.float  "official_rating", default: 0.0
    t.float  "rating",          default: 0.0
    t.string "ptype"
    t.string "year"
    t.string "imdb"
    t.string "tmdb"
    t.string "tvdb"
    t.string "wiki"
    t.string "poster"
    t.string "backdrop"
    t.string "trailer"
    t.float  "popularity",      default: 0.0
  end

  create_table "program_schedules", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "program_id"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "stop"
    t.integer  "channel_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `includes` should include the association not the table name in symbolic form.  Try changing your default scope to the following:

```
default_scope { includes(:channel).where("channels.ctype NOT IN (?)", ['tv']) }
```

Comment: Tried. I get PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "channels"

Comment: @user1028100 Add `.joins(:channel)` as well. The `.includes` will result in a second query to eager load the association, however the first query will not intuitively generate an `INNER JOIN`. This is not normally a problem until you attempt to reference the eager-loaded-but-not-joined table in the `WHERE` clause, as you have done.

Comment: Same thing. I tried:
"default_scope { joins(:channel).where("channels.ctype NOT IN (?)", ['tv']) }"
and 
"default_scope { joins(:channel).includes(:channel).where("channels.ctype NOT IN (?)", ['tv']) }"

Comment: @user1028100, it doesn't look like the query you've posted screenshot of is a result of the ActiveRecord query in question.  Can you post the exact query that's generating that error?

Answer (score 3):

**I'm posting this as an "answer", but it is intended as a comment. I am doing this so that I can illustrate my explanation better. Let me know if / when you'd like me to remove this non-answer.**

I have tried to replicate your problem, and I simply cannot do so using the query and `default_scope` you've posted so far. Ultimately, the problem is that your `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  condition is referencing a table that has not yet been joined. Even though it is joined later in the query, the interpreter cannot see that far ahead.

This is the part I'm referring to (formatted for readability):

```
...FROM "programs" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        "program_schedules" 
            ON "program_schedules"."program_id" = "programs"."id" 
                AND (channels.ctype NOT IN ...)
                     ^^^
                     Problem is here. The channels table has not yet been joined.
```

Additionally, I have *never* seen a `.where` appending to the join condition. If you're using that method, ActiveRecord *should* be placing whatever you passed to the `.where` method in the `WHERE` clause, as you'd expect. For some reason, it is obviously appending your condition to the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as an `AND` condition.

The only way I know to append conditions to the join, is by using the `.joins` method, something like this:

```
...joins(" AND program_schedules.channels.ctype NOT IN (?)", ['tv'])
```

That will indeed result in a query like this (truncated for brevity):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "program_schedules" ON ... AND program_schedules.channels......
```

In addition, the generated query in the error message states

```
(channels.ctype NOT IN ...)
```

as the failing join condition, whereas your `.where` condition states

```
program_schedules.channels.ctype
```

I don't see anywhere else in your question where you've written anything that looks like that part of the query in the error message. So again, it seems like we're not quite seeing everything.

It seems like we are still missing some pieces of information. Is it possible you do indeed have something like the `.join` condition I wrote above? Are there other `default_scopes` in other models that could be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this StackOverflow question when I was researching a similar issue that I'm seeing in my application. I *think* that using `default_scope` with `joins` is just broken.

I boiled your code down to something simple that would fail, ran `Program.joins(:program_schedules).to_sql` and got the following sql:

```
SELECT "programs".*
FROM "programs"
INNER JOIN "program_schedules" ON
  "program_schedules"."program_id" = "programs"."id" AND 
  ("channels"."ctype" NOT IN ('tv'))
```

The problem isn't that it hasn't joined to `channels` yet, it is that it will **never** join to channels. The where clause from the `default_scope` got tacked into the `INNER JOIN`, but the join was discarded.

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :programs
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :program_schedules
end

class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :channel

  default_scope { joins(:channel).where.not(channels: { ctype: ['tv'] }) }
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140331124327) do
  create_table "channels", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "site"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "icon"
    t.string   "ctype"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "lang"
    t.integer  "ordertab"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "homepage"
  end

  create_table "programs", force: true do |t|
    t.string "country"
    t.string "title"
    t.text   "subtitle"
    t.text   "description"
    t.float  "official_rating", default: 0.0
    t.float  "rating",          default: 0.0
    t.string "ptype"
    t.string "year"
    t.string "imdb"
    t.string "tmdb"
    t.string "tvdb"
    t.string "wiki"
    t.string "poster"
    t.string "backdrop"
    t.string "trailer"
    t.float  "popularity",      default: 0.0
  end

  create_table "program_schedules", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "program_id"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "stop"
    t.integer  "channel_id"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12896

In activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb there's a comment with the next:

```
# If you need to do more complex things with a default scope, you can
# alternatively define it as a class method:
#
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.default_scope
    # Should return a scope, you can call 'super' here etc.
  end
end
```

Which worked for me.